# How to do error handling for "unhandled intent" asked by user in Alexa?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

When alexa receives "unhandled intent" from users. How to handle error messages "Am not quite sure how to help you with that"?

Answer (score 4):

STEP 1 : 
You might be getting lot of unhandled events if your interaction Model lacks in sample uttrances. More examples you add there will redirect your alexa skill to correct functions...

Refer this link for setting up your interaction model correctly https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/define-the-interaction-model-in-json-and-text.html#h2_sample_utterances

STEP 2: Define unhandled function in your index.js to handle the exceptions and reprompt user to enter correct word

```
'Unhandled': function () {
    this.attributes.speechOutput = this.t('HELP_MESSAGE');
    this.attributes.repromptSpeech = this.t('HELP_REPROMPT');
    this.emit(':ask', this.attributes.speechOutput, this.attributes.repromptSpeech);
},
```